# How can I make my blur animation works faster everytime?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blur

I try to blur all my page and show a "popup form" when I click on a button, this actually work, but the animation is really slow the first time I click, so I try to find any solution to fix this

I run it on a local wamp server, I've tried with a lot of browser, and everytime the first click seems slow, I even tried to upload the website online and this is the same result.

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid");
vid.volume = 0.01;
var x = document.getElementById("formregister");
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var top_vid =
document.getElementById('top_vid')

function hideShow()
{
  if(x.style.display === "none")
  {
    x.style.display = "block";
    vid.classList.remove('noblur');
    top_vid.classList.remove('noblur');
    vid.className += " blur";
    top_vid.className += " blur";
  }
  else
  {
    x.style.display = "none";
    vid.className += " noblur";
    top_vid.className += " noblur";
    vid.classList.remove('blur');
    top_vid.classList.remove('blur');
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
body{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}

.bg,
.bg-filter{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
 }

.bg-filter{
  z-index:-99;
  opacity:0.2;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(49,224,247,1) 0%, rgba(90,77,184,1) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(49,224,247,1) 0%, rgba(90,77,184,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(49,224,247,1) 0%, rgba(90,77,184,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(49,224,247,1) 0%, rgba(90,77,184,1) 100%);
}

.top_vid{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.top_vid .title{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 3%;
  font-size:3.2em;
  color:#fff;
}

.start {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 3%;
}
.start:focus{
  outline:none;
}
.start span {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;

}
.start span:after {
  color: #31E0F7;
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.start:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.start:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
.registerform{
  align-items: center;
}
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
}
.noblur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
```

```html
  <div id="container">

    <video autoplay loop poster class="bg" id="bgvid">
      <source src="videos/theforcebg5.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    </video>

    <div class="bg-filter" id="bg-filter"></div>

    <div class="top_vid" id="top_vid">
      <h1 class="title">Moodyness</h1>
      <button class="start" onclick="hideShow()"><span>Let's move !</span></button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="registerform" id="formregister" style="display: none;">

    <form action="#" method="post">
      <input type="email" placeholder="EMAIL" required></input>
      <input type="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" required></input>
      <input type="password" placeholder="REPEAT PASSWORD" required></input>

      <div class="check">
        <label for="checkbox">Acceptez vous les conditions d'utilisation ?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" required></input>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" value="Okay !"></input>
    </form>

  </div>
```

And the full code is here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pmWwxm

I want the animation to be fast even the first time we launch the website, thanks you !

Comment: It seems fine for me, although I'm not entirely sure what animation you are talking about. I assume it's the one that shows once you click `Let's Move`.

Comment: You should start by fixing the html markup. Also note that there is a js function called `toggle` for classList which makes add and remove redundant https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That really doesn't has much to do with JavaScript or HTML, at all. It is a CSS property that is handling the time of the blur animation (or [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)).

You can handle the time of the transition in this four lines:

```css
.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in; //HERE
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in; //HERE
}
.noblur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out; //HERE
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out; //HERE
}
```

You had the values:

```css
transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
```

So changing it to a smaller value like `0.1s` will make the transition faster. This is why your transition has always the same speed since `transition` CSS property handles the time between the current element style to the next style.

**Example:** Having `blur(5px)` as current value, when you change the element style to `blur(0px)` and the `transition` property is present on the element, CSS will calc how much does it need to reduce the current value in the specified time `5s` so at the end of this time, the final value will be `blur(0px)`. This simulates the blur animation disappearing.

Take a look here so you can see it working:

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid");
vid.volume = 0.01;
var x = document.getElementById("formregister");
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var top_vid =
document.getElementById('top_vid')

function hideShow()
{
  if(x.style.display === "none")
  {
    x.style.display = "block";
    vid.classList.remove('noblur');
    top_vid.classList.remove('noblur');
    vid.className += " blur";
    top_vid.className += " blur";
  }
  else
  {
    x.style.display = "none";
    vid.className += " noblur";
    top_vid.className += " noblur";
    vid.classList.remove('blur');
    top_vid.classList.remove('blur');
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
body{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}

.bg,
.bg-filter{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
 }

.bg-filter{
  z-index:-99;
  opacity:0.2;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(49,224,247,1) 0%, rgba(90,77,184,1) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(49,224,247,1) 0%, rgba(90,77,184,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(49,224,247,1) 0%, rgba(90,77,184,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(49,224,247,1) 0%, rgba(90,77,184,1) 100%);
}

.top_vid{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.top_vid .title{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 3%;
  font-size:3.2em;
  color:#fff;
}

.start {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 3%;
}
.start:focus{
  outline:none;
}
.start span {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.1s;

}
.start span:after {
  color: #31E0F7;
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.1s;
}
.start:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.start:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}
.registerform{
  align-items: center;
}
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
}
.noblur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

    <video autoplay loop poster class="bg" id="bgvid">
      <source src="videos/theforcebg5.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    </video>

    <div class="bg-filter" id="bg-filter"></div>

    <div class="top_vid" id="top_vid">
      <h1 class="title">Moodyness</h1>
      <button class="start" onclick="hideShow()"><span>Let's move !</span></button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="registerform" id="formregister" style="display: none;">

    <form action="#" method="post">
      <input type="email" placeholder="EMAIL" required></input>
      <input type="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" required></input>
      <input type="password" placeholder="REPEAT PASSWORD" required></input>

      <div class="check">
        <label for="checkbox">Acceptez vous les conditions d'utilisation ?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" required></input>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" value="Okay !"></input>
    </form>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, this is not totally what I was asking, it was the fact that the first time I click on "Let's move" the animation seems laggy, like the animation doesn't work well and is not smooth, the next time I click its what I want, but maybe you don't have the problem, and it comes from my computer, anyway thanks you !

Comment: @Teddy You should've mention that in your question, the fact of a "laggy" animation may be due to different things. Could be your JavaScript code overloading, an infinite loop or even your browser available memory. My answer only solved the title of your question, which was make the blur transition faster.

Comment: @Teddy I edited my answer and code, check the snippet and see if making the animation of the "Lets move" element faster stills give you the "laggy" animation.

Comment: Works blazing fast for me whereas the original had a noticeable lag

Comment: @MoritzRoessler What do you mean by "lag"? Delay?

Comment: @k3llydev No, not a delay, more like a drag, it feels as if the gpu can't handle it. Maybe it's because i only have a HD 3000 and chrome needs to cpu emulate most of the gpu stuff i guess.